# DFP Video Creative

Tags: google-dfp

I need help on the video creative for DFP (for publishers).  I see a lot of discussion on building ads that run before a video.

However, I, simply, want to have a 1-minute video play as the creative, instead of a static image.

I followed the steps in DFP to create an ad unit with both a normal size and a VAST size.  The 'Generate Tags' result is:

```
https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=300x250|300x250|300x600&iu=/1028***/GGB_video_1&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&url=[referrer_url]&description_url=[description_url]&correlator=[timestamp]
```

It's not clear what to do with this link?  Obviously, it's not formatted as a normal DFP tag set.  Note, my creative is a youtube video.

OR - Is it preferable to do a normal ad unit and use the HTML5 creative for a video?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check if your vast is working and serving the video creative. You can use the [Vast Inspector](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector).

Second you will need a video player. The video player uses the vast url to build the video creative with the  [IMA SDK 3](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/)

Google provide a list of video partners:
https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/186110?hl=en

if you will use Sambatech, there is an example using javascript API:

```
        player = new SambaPlayer("player", {
            height: 360,
            width: 640,
            ph: "",
            m: "",
            playerParams: {
                enableShare: true,
                wideScreen: false,
                autoStart: false,
                ad_program: /** vast tag here*/,
                html5: true,
                sambatech: true 
            },
            events: {
                onLoad: "eventListener",
                onStart: "eventListener",
                onFinish: "eventListener",
                onResizeActive: "eventListener",
                onResizeDeactive: "eventListener",
                onPause: "eventListener",
            }
        });
```